# Gets icon prop and passing it into styled() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am getting icon prop and passing it to styled function to create a stylized icon based on it

```
const IconComponent = ({ isActive, icon }) => {
   const StyledIcons = styled(icon)`
      fill: #1f6ed4;
      & path {
         fill: ${(props) => (props.isActive ? '#1F6ED4' : '#232323')};
      }
   `
   return <StyledIcons isActive={isActive} />
}
```

**it works**, but I am getting warnings like below:

[image: console]

Is there any other way to create my `StyledIcons` component
and at the same time receive the icon prop ?

Comment: I'm new to React so I'm asking for any advice and guidance
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must move your `StyledIcons` outside the `IconComponent` component and use the [`as` prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) to pass your `icon` component:

```
const StyledIcons = styled.svg`
  fill: #1f6ed4;
  & path {
    fill: ${(props) => (props.isActive ? '#1F6ED4' : '#232323')};
  }
`

const IconComponent = ({ isActive, icon }) => {
    
  return <StyledIcons as={icon} isActive={isActive} />
};
```

Working example

[image: Edit styled-components dynamic component]

And if you don't have control over the `icon` prop and want to avoid the second warning

> Warning: React does not recognize the `isActive` prop on a DOM element...

you can prefix the `isActive` prop with a dollar sign ($), turning it into a [transient prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props):

```
const StyledIcons = styled.svg`
  fill: #1f6ed4;
  & path {
    fill: ${(props) => (props.$isActive ? "#1F6ED4" : "#232323")};
  }
`;

const IconComponent = ({ isActive, icon }) => {
  return <StyledIcons as={icon} $isActive={isActive} />;
};
```

Comment: BLess you God 